# How to show a custom error message for DisplayFormat attribute In Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

How to show a custom error message for

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
```

The code in my model is following,

```
[Display(Name = "When was that document issued?")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessageResourceName = "DocumentIssueDate_DataType",ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CustomErrorMessages))]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
 public DateTime? DocumentIssueDate { get; set; }
```

In my View when I enter 201 in the date textbox I get the following error message. How do I modify the error message below.

> The value '201' is not valid for DocumentIssueDate.

Comment: What do you have for `DocumentIssueDate_DataType`?

Comment: A string message in the resource file (.resx). For e.g.
"Date must be entered as dd/mm/yyyy (e.g. 31/01/1997)."

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research I had no luck. The only solution was to use `RegularExpression`.

Instead of using:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
```

You can use:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])[-/](1[0-2]|0[1-9])[-/][0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Date Not Valid")]
```

The `RegularExpression` matches the date format `dd/MM/yyyy`.

regular still not test yes but you can search and edit if need

Answer (score 0):

Try see answers [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921928/displayformat-dataannotation-not-working) I think DisplayFormat designed not for validation, that is why you can not use it to check if entered string is valid.