# MVC3 How to define custom error messages using annotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a DateTime field(that can accept multiple date time formats, so it is pain to create Regex patter)

When in the field I'm entering something like "Aaaaaa", I'm getting error message:

```
The value 'Aaaaa' is not valid for OwnerBirthDate
```

Model looks:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
public DateTime? OwnerBirthDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OwnerBirthDate)
```

How can I define custom error message for this particular field?

Thank you

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176663/how-to-replace-standard-dataannotations-error-messages

Comment: If you want to validate that the value that is being entered by the user in the corresponding input field you will have to write a custom model binder.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921928/displayformat-dataannotation-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You can use ValidationMessageFor to apply a custom message if you want a different message to one pre defined in an attribute

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OwnerBirthDate, "custom error message")
```

Comment: getting the same... not even rendered, any ideas why?

Comment: You still need to use `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OwnerBirthDate)`.  The above is in addition for a custom error.

Comment: I do, but in controller in model state I'm seeing old error message. @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OwnerBirthDate, "custom error message") - bot even rendered

Comment: Adding code: <div id = "test">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OwnerBirthDate,   custom error message")
            </div> In genrated output(in browser) i can see empty <div id="test">